# Get a string variable from views to urls in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, python-requests, django-urls

I am a beginner at Python and Django, I am trying to solve a problem where when a user searches if that search is valid, I want to get that search = `var_X`, in my URL like:

```
www.website.com/search/var_X
```

or something like,

```
www.website.com/search/<df.item>
```

Views.py

```py
def views_search(request):
    temp_dict = {}
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        var_X = request.POST['var_X']
        try:
            df = wsc.Summary(temp_dict, var_X)
        except Exception as e:
            df = "ERROR"
            return render(request,'search.html', {'df' : df})
    else:
        return render(request,'home.html', {'var_X' : "Not Found"})
```

Urls

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from requests import *

urlpatterns = [
   path('search/<var_X>', views.views_search, name="url-search"),
]
```

HTML

```html
<form action="{% url 'url-search' var_X %}"class="d-flex" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Enter String" aria-label="Search" name="var_X">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Django renders a template it converts all template tags into html.

You won't be able to set the value of `var_X` in `{% url 'url-search' var_X %}` using python code on the client side.

My suggestion is to use javascript to set the form's action using the `onclick` html attribute.

```html
<button ... onclick="this.form.action = {% url 'url-search' %} + document.getElementById('id-of-input-element').value;>"
```

This also means removing the `action` attribute from the input element.

From

```html
<form action="{% url 'url-search' var_X %}"class="d-flex" method="POST">
```

to

```html
<form class="d-flex" method="POST">
```

Because I don't know what your code does (because I don't know what `df` is. Use the following as only an example of what you could achieve.

(In my code snippets entering a search goes back to the same page to display results.)

`urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
   path('search/', views.views_search, name="url-search"),
   path('search/<str:var_X>', views.views_search)
]
```

The route `'search/'` is needed in order to make `{% url 'url-search' %}` work on first page load.

The route `'search/<str:var_X>'` matches any value after `search/` into a variable called `var_X` as a string in the view function.

`views.py`

```py
def views_search(request, var_X=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
        # do the stuff you need to do with the form..
    return render(
        request,
        "views_search.html",
        {
            'var_X': var_X
        }
    )
```

The parameter `var_X` is `None` by default if the url doesn't have anything after `search/` else it will have the search string.

`views_search.html` (wtv your html template is called)

```html
<form class="d-flex" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id="search_input" class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Enter String" aria-label="Search" name="var_X" value="">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" onclick="this.form.action = {% url 'url-search' %} + document.getElementById('search_input').value;">Search</button>
</form>

{% if var_X %}
    <p>Showing results for '{{ var_X }}'.</p>
{% endif %}
```

with the above html you'll get this output:

Before pressing search button

[image: form before]

After pressing search button

[image: form after]

This also has the benefit that if you type something directly into the url it will search that too.

#### Hopefully this helps steer you in the right direction for what you're looking for.